# A DT sequence y[n] is constructed from another DT sequence x[n]

Tags: dtft

A DT sequence $y[n]$ is constructed from another DT sequence $x[n]$ according to the
formula $y[n]=x[nN]$, where $N$ is a constant positive integer greater than one. (This process is usually called decimation, although this name would strictly be appropriate only if $N = 10$.)

a) Sketch a typical $x[n]$ and the corresponding $y[n]$ for, say, $N=3$.

b) Suggest a set of conditions to be imposed on the DTFT of $x[n]$ such that it will
be possible to reconstruct $x[n]$ for all $n$ from $y[n]$ .

c) Describe a specific scheme for carrying out the reconstruction if the conditions of (b) apply.

d) The conditions on $x[n]$ that are sufficient to permit reconstruction of $x[n]$ for all $n$ given $y[n]$ are not unique. Describe at least one set of conditions different from those in (b) that will also suffice .

Thank you

Comment: Welcome here. Could you provide us with your first steps, and what blocks your subsequent reasoning?

Comment: Not very well mastered this topic. I solve similar problems to understand,but there are difficulties. I would be very grateful if you can help me!

Comment: @John We'll help you! But understand we can't do your homework for you (that won't really help you). Please help us and show what you understand thus far, starting with step (a). Please show us your work so we understand where you are stuck. To sketch a typical x[n] means to draw a stem plot of ANY sample sequence such as 1, 5, -3, 2, 10, -2, 6 out to about 15 samples or so and then do what it says-----take it from there!

Comment: Let x[3n] be δ[3n], then y[n]=δ[3n]. I understand how to portray the δ-function. But what to do next, I don't understand(

Comment: Can anyone help? I can't do it without your help.